# Which is the clean way of binding MongoDB collections with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am a SQL user and I try to understand how to work in a clean way with **MongoDB** and to **Meteor**.

My program is simple :

List objects according to category (an object belongs in only one category).
I would thus like that my program posts(shows) my objects in this way:

- Category1

  - ObjectA
  - ObjectB
- Category2

  - ObjectC
  - ObjectD

Of what I understood, I created at first my collections:

```
Objects = new Mongo.Collection(objects);
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
```

To say that the object X belongs to the category1,do I have to define id of the category in the object?

```
Objects.update(objectId,{
    categorieId : categorieId
}) ;
```

Or I have to define the object category in Object

```
Objects.update(objectId,{
    categorie : categorieObject
}) ;
```

But I also have to make it for the category ?

```
Categories.update(categoriesId,{
    Objects: [objectObject] //But how to define one more without crushing those already existing?
}) ;
```

**I would like to understand how to make these connections without weighing down my database and without making too much requests.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer as it depends on your application needs.
What really matters is usage of your app. 
How big will be `traffic`, `ratio read/write`. How often you are going to update `Categories`?

### Application with huge traffic

If your app should be heavily optimized (big traffic) then you would like to have as little subscriptions as possible. 
In that case you probably would like to embed `Category` within `Object` document as accessing `Category` from `Object` doesn't require any extra work to do.

The drawback of this solution will occur when you would like to change anything in `Category` object, you will have to iterate over all `Objects` and update accordingly.

### Application with small traffic

In this situation I would reference `Category` from `Object` by using `categorieId` field. There is nice [package Astronomy](https://atmospherejs.com/jagi/astronomy) which helps 'creating joins' :

```
Object = new Astro.Class( {
    name: 'Object',
    collection: Objects,
    fields: {
        'categorieId' : {type:"String"}
    },
    validators:{
        'categorieId' : Validators.isCategorie() 
    },
    methods:{
        category: function(){
           return Categories.findOne({_id:this.categorieId})
        }
    }
} )
```

On `server side` you can very easily access `Category` using:

```
Objects.findOne({_id:"<some existing id>"}).category()
```

On `client side` above code will work if you subscribe properly to `Categories`.

Keep in my mind that this topic is much broader and deeper.